# OrchardCore match_phrase doesn't return result

Tags: elasticsearch, orchardcms

I have the following query

```
{
  "from": 0, "size": 10000,
  "query": { "match_phrase": {"Practitioner.DoctorList": "peter goh"} },
}
```

it doesn't return any result.

But the following:

```
{
  "from": 0, "size": 10000,
  "query": { "match": {"Practitioner.DoctorList": "peter goh"} },
}
```

returns content that has "peter goh", "peter", and "goh".

Why doesn't `match_phrase` return anything? As I only want the results to have matches with "peter goh".

Comment: Can you please share mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not added any sample data and index mapping, (considering `Practitioner` to be of `nested` type)

Refer [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) query, to get detailed information

Adding a working example with index data, mapping and search query.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Practitioner": {
        "type": "nested" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "Practitioner": [
        {
            "DoctorList": "goh"
        },
        {
            "DoctorList": "peter goh"
        },
        {
            "DoctorList": "peter"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "Practitioner",
      "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "Practitioner.DoctorList": "peter goh"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits":{}
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "fd_cb3",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "Practitioner",
                    "offset": 1
                  },
                  "_score": 0.78038335,
                  "_source": {
                    "DoctorList": "peter goh"
                  }
                }
              ]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to OrchardCore. Is there a place to define this index mapping and index data in OrchardCore?